# Connecting a JSON file to a GUI interface using python

Tags: python, json

Hi all this is my post so apologies if I am not clear I am currently working on developing a interface that can connect to a JSON file that is a prototype for a much bigger project currently I have developed the interface which looks like this. Currently I want it to return some text that is present in the JSON depending on what is entered such as the id, name or source.
My issue is that I have the JSON file and the code for the interface which is present below currently being a beginner at coding I am unsure of the code used to to connect the JSON file to the interface so it would return the text that is present in the JSON string.

I have looked online for how to do this but it seems there is nothing to be found and I am hoping anyone on here can help.

picture of interface.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cszdl.png

code extract for the interface:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
btn = Button(window, text="Submit", fg='blue')
btn.place(x=120, y=120)
txtfld=Entry(window, text=" ", bd=5)
txtfld.place(x=80, y=50)
txtfld=Entry(window, text=" ", bd=5)
txtfld.place(x=80, y=20)
txtfld=Entry(window, text=" ", bd=5)
txtfld.place(x=80, y=80)
lbl=Label(window, text="DatasetName", fg='red', font=("Helvetica", 8))
lbl.place(x=10, y=20)
lbl=Label(window, text="DatasetID", fg='red', font=("Helvetica", 8))
lbl.place(x=23, y=50)
lbl=Label(window, text="Source", fg='red', font=("Helvetica", 8))
lbl.place(x=23, y=80)
window.title='Database interface'
window.geometry("300x200+40+20")
window.mainloop()
```

Json file string:

```json
{
   "datasetid":{
      "0":45
   },
   "name":{
      "0":"English indices of deprivation"
   },
   "source":{
      "0":"DfCLG: Department for Communities & Local Government"
   },
   "release_date":{
      "0":"2019-01-01"
   },
   "next_release_due":{
      "0":"2023-01-01"
   },
   "geo_ceil":{
      "0":"country"
   },
   "geo_floor":{
      "0":"ladistrict"
   },
   "year":{
      "0":true
   },
   "quarter":{
      "0":false
   },
   "month":{
      "0":false
   },
   "day":{
      "0":false
   },
   "week":{
      "0":false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
file = open("json_file_here.json")#make sure they r in same location to do this
data=json.load(file)#stores data from file in data variable
```

then from here on iterate through the data variable according to your need and use

```
txtfld.insert(0,"required filed here")
```

PS:- change name of entry fields to specify what needs to go where

Comment: Hi just wondering how would I iterate through the data variable would i need to use a loop

Comment: json.load return data in form of dictionary so u can use                   for k,v in data:   print(k,v) and experiment from there on